# nextJs take time to load css file

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

i'm working in nextJs springboot project.
i have problems in css load they take time to load.
when i open a page they come without css, after few second they turn with style
i create folder assets in public folder, then i put all my css files there, i can't use globals.css because i have a dashboard with specific css and the home page with another css.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gSmw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COCF4.png)

i need help to resolve this problem without use globals.css

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js supports CSS modules, and the SASS preprocessor as well. You can create a module for each of the different pages, and then use the SASS `@import` statement to load whatever you need in them. Here are [some docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support) and an example:

```scss
@import url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```